# Getting 500 server error in model service "Unable to perform action"

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0, model-service

We are using SDL Web 8.5 with DXA 2.0 Java. Model service is returning 500 server error while accessing any page without HTML extension while using HTML extension it is working fine we are getting below errors

**Whitelabel error page in browser**

Whitelabel Error Page

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Jan 23 17:31:33 AST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Unable to perform action
```

**Error logged in model service log file**

```
    2019-01-23 17:35:35,822 DEBUG o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@ddafd79 
2019-01-23 17:35:35,869 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/PageModel/tcm/10//en/about/governor/profile] 
2019-01-23 17:35:35,869 DEBUG o.s.b.a.e.m.EndpointHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /PageModel/tcm/10/en/about/governor/profile 
2019-01-23 17:35:35,869 DEBUG o.s.b.a.e.m.EndpointHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/PageModel/tcm/10/en/about/governor/profile] 
2019-01-23 17:35:35,885 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /PageModel/tcm/10/en/about/governor/profile 
2019-01-23 17:35:35,885 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.sdl.dxa.modelservice.controller.PageModelController.getPage(java.lang.String,int,com.sdl.dxa.common.dto.PageRequestDto$PageInclusion,com.sdl.dxa.common.dto.DataModelType,boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.ContentProviderException,com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException] 
2019-01-23 17:35:35,885 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'pageModelController' 
2019-01-23 17:35:35,885 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/PageModel/tcm/10//en/about/governor/profile] is: -1 
2019-01-23 17:35:35,885 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.modelServiceLocalizationIdProvider' 
2019-01-23 17:35:35,885 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'scopedTarget.modelServiceLocalizationIdProvider' 
2019-01-23 17:35:35,885 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'cacheManager' 
2019-01-23 17:35:35,885 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'cacheManager' 
2019-01-23 17:35:35,885 DEBUG c.s.d.m.s.ContentService - Trying to request a page with localization id = '10' and path = '/en/about/governor/profile' 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,911 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.sdl.dxa.modelservice.controller.PageModelController.getPage(java.lang.String,int,com.sdl.dxa.common.dto.PageRequestDto$PageInclusion,com.sdl.dxa.common.dto.DataModelType,boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.ContentProviderException,com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException]: com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientRuntimeException: Unable to perform action 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,911 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.sdl.dxa.modelservice.controller.PageModelController.getPage(java.lang.String,int,com.sdl.dxa.common.dto.PageRequestDto$PageInclusion,com.sdl.dxa.common.dto.DataModelType,boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.ContentProviderException,com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException]: com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientRuntimeException: Unable to perform action 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,911 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.sdl.dxa.modelservice.controller.PageModelController.getPage(java.lang.String,int,com.sdl.dxa.common.dto.PageRequestDto$PageInclusion,com.sdl.dxa.common.dto.DataModelType,boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.ContentProviderException,com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException]: com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientRuntimeException: Unable to perform action 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,911 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request 
com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientRuntimeException: Unable to perform action
    at com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.performAction(DefaultODataClient.java:93)
    at com.sdl.web.content.client.impl.ContentClient.lambda$performAction$6(ContentClient.java:263)
    at com.sdl.web.content.client.impl.ClientRequestRetrySupporter$RetryBlock.execute(ClientRequestRetrySupporter.java:60)
    at com.sdl.web.content.client.impl.ClientRequestRetrySupporter.runWithRetry(ClientRequestRetrySupporter.java:27)
    at com.sdl.web.content.client.impl.ContentClient.performAction(ContentClient.java:262)
    at com.sdl.web.content.client.ContentClientApi.performAction(ContentClientApi.java:43)
    at com.sdl.web.api.broker.querying.QueryImpl.executeQuery(QueryImpl.java:128)
    at com.sdl.dxa.modelservice.service.ContentService.loadPageContent(ContentService.java:85)
    at com.sdl.dxa.modelservice.service.ContentService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8da11676.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:408)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:327)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.sdl.dxa.modelservice.service.ContentService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38576dee.loadPageContent(<generated>)
    at com.sdl.dxa.modelservice.service.DefaultPageModelService.loadPageModel(DefaultPageModelService.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:408)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:327)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.loadPageModel(Unknown Source)
    at com.sdl.dxa.modelservice.controller.PageModelController.getPage(PageModelController.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1693)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.processSocket(AbstractEndpoint.java:946)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$4.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:626)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$4.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:604)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientException: Unable to process response from OData service.
    at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.getResponse(BasicEndpointCaller.java:223)
    at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.sendRequest(BasicEndpointCaller.java:148)
    at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.doPostEntity(BasicEndpointCaller.java:108)
    at com.sdl.odata.client.DefaultODataClient.performAction(DefaultODataClient.java:84)
    ... 114 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sdl.odata.client.caller.BasicEndpointCaller.getResponse(BasicEndpointCaller.java:186)
    ... 117 common frames omitted
2019-01-23 17:35:45,911 DEBUG o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@ddafd79 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,927 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error] 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,927 DEBUG o.s.b.a.e.m.EndpointHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /error 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,942 DEBUG o.s.b.a.e.m.EndpointHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/error] 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,942 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /error 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,942 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)] 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,942 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController' 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,942 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,942 DEBUG o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html]) 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,942 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'error' 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,942 DEBUG o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@22ae905f] based on requested media type 'text/html' 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,942 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@22ae905f] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' 
2019-01-23 17:35:45,942 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

**Note**

The error is randomly occurring after restarting model service sometime errors fixed automatically

Comment: seems like the server is trying to read data from the request, but it's taking longer than the timeout value for the data to arrive from the client, Can you increase the ConnectionTimeout in the cd_client
_conf.config, Is it service running in Windows or Linux server? If it's windows give a service delay startup

Comment: @velmurugan i have increased timeout values but still getting same error

Comment: other important thing it always loading fine if i add .html in request url

Comment: what is the settings on dxa.properties of the dxa.web.link-resolver.remove-extension & dxa.web.link-resolver.strip-index-path?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Content Service logs?

Answer (score 1):

It was an environment issue. DXA web application was deployed on load balance environment have two windows application server and we configured one cluster between two application that cluster was causing issue so we have added localhost entry in host file and resolved the issue